# Using keytool to list secret key

Tags: java, keytool, key-management, tls-psk

I used keytool to generate the secret key:

```
keytool -genseckey -alias mykey -keyalg AES -keysize 256 -storetype jceks -keystore mykeystore
```

Then, the following command will list information about `mykeystore`:

```
keytool -list -keystore mykeystore -storepass password -v -storetype jceks -alias mykey
```

And the result will like it:

> Alias name: mykey
>   Creation date: Dec 31, 2016
>   Entry type: SecretKeyEntry

But I want to see the key like below(I used `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k secret -P -md sh1` ):

> salt=xxxxxxxxxxx
>   key=EB381B48CC2D39C7A5164491129CA10486861530B02E4FD11D64433CF8388428
>   
> iv = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

How to use keytool to see the key from keystore?

Comment: You'll have to use Java code for that. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907622/keytool-see-the-public-and-private-keys

Comment: Java `KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry` is a raw key, i.e. the correct number of random bits, stored in bytes. `openssl enc` in most cases including this does salted Password Based Key Derivation (PBKDF) to produce a key and sometimes (including here) IV entirely different from the input password. Standard Java JCE called from code (but not `keytool`) supports some PBKDF algorithms, but not the one used by `openssl`, which is named `EVP_BytesToKey` and there are quite a few Qs about it already. However it is a poor PBKDF; if you want PBE and don't need openssl interop you should use ...

Comment: ... something better like PBKDF2 or depending on your usage maybe bcrypt, scrypt, argon2. In any case, TLS-PSK does not do any kind of PBKDF, although it does alter the TLS 'PRF' which is really a KBKDF (**Key** Based Key Derivation) which is quite different from a PBKDF. In short, your Q is combining things that make no sense together.